# ReactNative ListView with Json Api

Tags: android, json, listview, react-native

I can't display json data in listview. I get json data in console.log but not in listview isLoading is always on false. 
I dont get any errors  .catch(error => console.warn("error")).
Result on screen is first View because this.state.isLoading is false.

Here is a code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, StyleSheet, ListView, Text, View,Image,TouchableHighlight } from 'react-native';

var productArray = [];

class ListViewDemo extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
    console.warn("constructor");
    super(props);
    var dataSource = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged:(r1,r2) => r1.guid != r2.guid});
   this.state = {
      dataSource: dataSource.cloneWithRows(productArray),
     isLoading:true
   }
 }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.warn("componentDidMount");
    this.getTheData(function(json){
     productArray = json;
      console.warn(productArray);
     this.setState = ({
       datasource:this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(productArray),
       isLoading:false
     })
    }.bind(this));   
     console.warn("component ->  " + this.state.isLoading);
  }

  getTheData(callback) {
    console.warn("callback");
    var url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/darkarmyIN/React-Native-DynamicListView/master/appledata.json";
fetch(url)
     .then(response => response.json())
     .then(json => callback(json))
     .catch(error => console.warn("error"));
   }

  renderRow(rowData, sectionID, rowID) {
    console.warn("renderRow");
    return (
        <TouchableHighlight underlayColor='#dddddd' style={{height:44}}>
         <View>
         <Text style={{fontSize: 20, color: '#000000'}} numberOfLines={1}>{rowData.display_string}</Text>
         <Text style={{fontSize: 20, color: '#000000'}} numberOfLines={1}>test</Text>
         <View style={{height: 1, backgroundColor: '#dddddd'}}/>
        </View>
    </TouchableHighlight>
);
}

   render() {
   console.warn("render" + this.state.isLoading);
   var currentView = (this.state.isLoading) ? <View style={{height: 110, backgroundColor: '#dddddd'}} /> : <ListView dataSource={this.state.dataSource} renderRow={this.renderRow.bind(this)} enableEmptySections={true}/>
   return(
     <View>
       {currentView}
     </View>
   );
  }
}

// App registration and rendering
AppRegistry.registerComponent('AwesomeProject', () => ListViewDemo);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a couple of mistakes here.

In your `componentDidMount`, you are setting `datasource` intead of `dataSource`:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    console.warn("componentDidMount");
    this.getTheData(function(json){
     productArray = json;
      console.warn(productArray);
     this.setState = ({
       //datasource:this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(productArray),
       dataSource:this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(productArray),
       isLoading:false
     })
    }.bind(this));   
     console.warn("component ->  " + this.state.isLoading);
  }
```

That's why you're not being able to render, because `dataSource` is never populated. It is just a little spelling mistake.

You are probably not getting into the second then in your getTheData method because you are not returning a Promise:

```
getTheData(callback) {
  console.warn("callback");
  var url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/darkarmyIN/React-Native-DynamicListView/master/appledata.json";
  fetch(url)
     //.then(response => response.json())
     .then(response => return response.json())
     .then(json => callback(json))
     .catch(error => console.warn("error"));
   }
```

Your are making a mistake with your `setState`, your are assigning it instead of calling it:

```
 //this.setState = ({
 //  datasource:this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(productArray),
 //  isLoading:false
 //})

 this.setState({
   dataSource:this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(productArray),
   isLoading:false
 })
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: Ok, let's try something, change your renderRow from `renderRow(rowData, sectionID, rowID)` to `renderRow(rowData)` and bind it in the constructor `this.renderRow = this.renderRow.bind(this);`. And put into a View your TouchableHighlight in the renderRow method.

Comment: same thing, the problem is that isLoading is alway on true when i log it

Comment: change your getData from `.then(response => response.json())` to `.then(response => return response.json())` . If you dont put `return` you are not going to enter in the second `then`.

Comment: Your setState is wrong, your are setting it instead of calling it. Check last update to my answer,

Comment: Yes,  setState was the problem, thanks a lot for your time

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the function `setState` instead of calling it

```js
this.setState = ({
    datasource:this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(productArray),
    isLoading:false
})
```

should be

```js
this.setState({
    datasource:this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(productArray),
    isLoading:false
})
```

Comment: Thanks man , it solved my problem .. i spend few hours on this error

Comment: Yep, that's happen...  
Do you understand what was your problem?