# Using API in react native

Tags: react-native

I am new in react native.I have an api address and i need some data from it to display as list.When i try to do it it does not shows the result. My code is written below. Please check it and help me to work this code. I need to print data such as:

SYMBOL,SUPPLY,FULLNAME,NAME,ID,VOLUME24HOURTO of each data

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, StyleSheet, FlatList, Text, View, Alert, ActivityIndicator, Platform} from 'react-native';

export default class Project extends React.Component {

  constructor(props)
  {

    super(props);

    this.state = { 
    isLoading: true
  }
  }

  componentDidMount() {

       return fetch('https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/top/volumes?tsym=BTC')
         .then((response) => response.json())
         .then((responseJson) => {
           this.setState({
             isLoading: false,
             dataSource: responseJson
           }, function() {
             // In this block you can do something with new state.
           });
         })
         .catch((error) => {
           console.error(error);
         });
     }

FlatListItemSeparator = () => {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          height: 1,
          width: "100%",
          backgroundColor: "#607D8B",
        }}
      />
    );
  }

  GetFlatListItem (FULLNAME) {

  Alert.alert(FULLNAME);

  }


  render() {

    if (this.state.isLoading) {
      return (
        <View style={{flex: 1, paddingTop: 20}}>
          <ActivityIndicator />
        </View>
      );
    }

    return (

<View style={styles.MainContainer}>

       <FlatList

          data={ this.state.dataSource }

          ItemSeparatorComponent = {this.FlatListItemSeparator}

          renderItem={({item}) => <Text style={styles.FlatListItemStyle} onPress={this.GetFlatListItem.bind(this, item.FULLNAME)} > {item.FULLNAME} </Text>}

          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}

         />


</View>

    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

MainContainer :{

justifyContent: 'center',
flex:1,
margin: 10,
paddingTop: (Platform.OS === 'ios') ? 20 : 0,

},

FlatListItemStyle: {
    padding: 10,
    fontSize: 18,
    height: 44,
  },

});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('Project', () => Project);
```

Comment: Is your data source an array of JSON objects? like [{FULLNAME:Hungry},{FULLNAME:Soul},{FULLNAME:HungrySoul}] ??

Answer (score 0):

The JSON response from the url is an object. Change to `dataSource: responseJson.Data` to get the array that can be rendered by `FlatList`.

Comment: render() {
  let data="kli";
   fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST', // or 'PUT'
   // body: JSON.stringify(url), // data can be `string` or {object}!
    headers: new Headers({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    })
  }).then(res => res.json())
  .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error))
  .then((response) =>{
    console.log('Success:',data);
    data=JSON.stringify(response);
    console.log('Success:',data);
    this.setState({
      data:JSON.stringify(response)
    })
  })
    return (
     <View>
    <Text>haiii {this.state.data}</Text>
    </View>

Comment: @sindhooritavm what?

Comment: return ( <View> <Text>haiii {this.state.data}</Text> </View> );

Comment: sry,
i cannot list it properly.now the data are display bt no proper listing

Comment: Not sure what you are talking. Please add code to OP and elaborate, or open a different question if it's unrelated.

Comment: actually sir here {this.state.data} is successfully working, but i need some particular data only .The result hold different array object and i need 2,3 fields like listing these data

Comment: Pls elaborate in post.

Comment: 13:08:17: Success: {"Data":[{"SYMBOL":"BCH","SUPPLY":17081750,"FULLNAME":"Bitcoin Cash / BCC (BCH)","NAME":"Bitcoin Cash
 / BCC","ID":"202330","VOLUME24HOURTO":38475.81896049033},{"SYMBOL":"ETH","SUPPLY":98913427.0615,"FULLNAME":"Ethereum (E
TH)","NAME":"Ethereum","ID":"7605","VOLUME24HOURTO":36309.49053856009},{"SYMBOL":"XRP","SUPPLY":38305873865,"FULLNAME":"

Comment: the result prints liks this,i just need to print few data

Comment: What have you tried? Please edit in your question, hard to read in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer any basic tutorial for build your need so you can easily understand all state and what changes you need. and also put console.log() for check log every state.

[for tutorial Flat list data show from Web-api](https://medium.com/react-native-development/how-to-use-the-flatlist-component-react-native-basics-92c482816fe6)

[For set datasource changes check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41963524/reactnative-listview-with-json-api?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: i get api datas btt the problem is i cannot list it properly